# How to combine 3 small theme css files and then click to select one

Tags: html, css

Currently I use three small external css files to change my site's theme colors and they work well. The themes apply to all pages on my site and are available for vision impaired users. However, I would like to reduce the number of requests to the server.

Could these three files be combined into one and invoked individually when selected, in a way similar to how media-queries work?

[My experimental site](http://12phillipstreet.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly combine these into one file and still apply each theme individually.

You could prefix each of your themes specific styles with a certain class. 
Then to switch between themes you could apply the class to `body` element.

e.g.

```
.theme1 .my-css-rule{
  color: black;
}

.theme2 .my-css-rule{
  color: white;
}

.theme3 .my-css-rule{
  color: green;
}
```

Then to apply the theme, you would set the class name of the theme on the body element:

```
<body class="theme1">
 ...
</body>
```

To set the theme and apply it to the body using javascript you could:

```
<button onclick="document.body.className = 'theme1';">Apply theme 1</button>
<button onclick="document.body.className = 'theme2';">Apply theme 2</button>
<button onclick="document.body.className = 'theme3';">Apply theme 3</button>
```

Comment: Stephen, thanks for your quick reply. Your suggestions are great but I think they would only apply to individual pages. Unfortunately my site has over 20 pages that I need to easily apply an alternative theme color to for vision impaired users. However, I will give your suggestions a try to see if they can be made to worl. Thanks again. JohnL

Comment: Yes, this would do the job just fine. Instead of loading an external stylesheet, you are instead just setting the class of the body. No matter what route you go down, you would still have to apply it to all of your pages. This option also gives you more flexibility if you want to change the theme dynamically using javascript.

Comment: Now that's looking very interesting. I will try your latest suggestion  on a couple of pages and perhaps have a go at some javascript as well. Many thanks jl